# Como recibo un conjunto de datos en una consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql

Necesito encontrar la forma de traer resultados asociados a un contenido en un arreglo

```
SELECT n.*, nf.url, nf.filename FROM noticias n INNER JOIN noticias_fotos nf ON nf.idNoticia = n.id WHERE n.fecha BETWEEN '2019-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-10 23:59:59' ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque en primera instancia parece correcto esto solo funciona para registros con 1 sola imagen, y ahí viene mi pregunta... Como hago para traer ese registro pero con un arreglo de cada imagen si tiene más de una.

resultado ahora:

```
[id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3,url_imagen]
```

Lo que necesito

```
[id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3,[url_imagen1,url_imagen2,etc]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como hago para traer ese registro pero con un arreglo de cada imagen si tiene más de una.

Técnicamente, no es posible con SQL, porque no existen los array en MySQL. Lo más que puedes hacer es hacer un GROUP_CONCAT sobre la columna que puede devolver diferentes valores en la consulta, tal que retorne los diferentes valores separados por comas. Pero eso es todo.
Cualquier otra solución es programática, y no por MySQL puro.

Algo parecido a esto:

```
SELECT id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3, GROUP_CONCAT(nf.url) url, GROUP_CONCAT(nf.filename) filename
FROM noticias n 
INNER JOIN noticias_fotos nf ON nf.idNoticia = n.id 
WHERE n.fecha BETWEEN '2019-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-10 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3
```

No hay que olvidar que una vez que usas el GROUP BY, no es posible que uses "*" en el SELECT...

Comment: Muchas gracias, con eso me trae todo separado por comas con lo que puedo trabajar sin necesidad de hacer muchas mas consultas por cada registro traido... GRACIAS!

Comment: Así me devuelve una cadena separada por comas y en php directamente las separo en un arreglo con explode y listo. Esta es la respuesta correcta :D

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar `LIMIT = 1`, de esta forma entregaría únicamente un resultado:

```
SELECT n.*, nf.url, nf.filename FROM noticias n INNER JOIN noticias_fotos nf ON nf.idNoticia = n.id WHERE n.fecha BETWEEN '2019-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-10 23:59:59' ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

Actualización:

Lo que obtiene el usuario es :

```
[id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3,url_imagen]
```

pero necesita un arreglo de las imágenes:

`[id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3,[url_imagen1,url_imagen2,etc]]`

En este caso no se puede generar un "array" de imágenes, pero puedes obtener el conjunto de las url, concatenarlas mediante [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) y agregarlas en un campo de la consulta:

```
SELECT n.*, GROUP_CONCAT(nf.url) urls, nf.filename 
FROM noticias n INNER JOIN noticias_fotos nf 
ON nf.idNoticia = n.id WHERE n.fecha BETWEEN '2019-07-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-10 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: En realidad ahora me da esto:

resultado: [id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3,url_imagen]

y yo necesito
[id,titulo,contenido1,contenido2,contenido3,[url_imagen1,url_imagen2,etc]]

Comment: No vale, las urls que vienen en diferentes tuplas por lo que con esto perderia información.

Comment: Es importante especificar ese tipo de información en tu pregunta, de esa forma te podemos apoyar de mejor manera, editaré mi respuesta. @MarianoCampos

Answer (score -1):

se me ocurre que puedes hacer la consulta normalmente, con la imagen 1 y la 2.
Lo único que en vez de traerte todo el registro en un único array, hazlo campo a campo.
Cuando lo estés recorriendo lo puedes montar como tu quieras.
Estoy hablando del lado server.
Te pongo un ejemplo en PHP.

```
$link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "USER", "PASS", "ESQUEMA_BBDD");
$link->set_charset("utf8") or die();

$consulta = "SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, CAMPO5 FROM ALIAS;";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);

$resultado_a_devolver = [];

while ($pos = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array_temp = [];
        $resultado1 = $pos[0]; //resultado: --> CAMPO1
        $resultado2 = $pos[1]; //resultado: --> CAMPO2
        $resultado3 = $pos[2]; //resultado: --> CAMPO3
        $resultado4 = $pos[3]; //resultado: --> CAMPO4
        $resultado5 = $pos[4]; //resultado: --> CAMPO5

        array_push($array_temp, $resultado4);
        array_push($array_temp, $resultado5);

        array_push($resultado_a_devolver , $resultado1);
        array_push($resultado_a_devolver , $resultado2);
        array_push($resultado_a_devolver , $resultado3);
        array_push($resultado_a_devolver , $array_temp);
}

echo json_encode(resultado_a_devolver);
```

Ya me dices si te vale! ;)

Comment: Esto no vale porque no las imagenes vienen en diferentes 'tuplas' y no en la misma.

Comment: Entonces, podriamos hacer un primer select para obtener todas la imagenes, Estas la ponemos en el array temporal. Despues hacemos la select con los datos y agregamos el array temporal a estos.

Comment: ¿Matar moscas a cañonazos? No, gracias

Comment: Funcionaria? si, entonces esta bien.

Comment: No, no esta bien. Una respuesta debe ser eficaz no una burrada. Mas cuando una solución ha sido propuesta y aprobada antes de poner tu una que no funciona y luego proponer una burrada.

Comment: Bueno, no lo he probado, pero yo creo que si funciona...

Comment: Y si en vez de hacerlo por una query, coge y pega en un txt todo tambien funcionaria .......

Comment: Yo creo que lo importante, mas que si son 'cañonazos' (tu lo consideras asi) es si funciona y si quien hizo la pregunta le ha quedado claro. Esto se resuelve asi: -QUERY-. Y quien hizo la pregunta se queda igual. Tal vez de este modo lo ve mas claro. Cañonazo o no.

Comment: No, lo mas importante es responder bien, esto implica que la respuesta funcione y que sea buena y optima, tu respuesta inicial no funcionaba y tu segunda respuesta es malisima porque no es optima, es hacer una chapuza. A mas inri, te repito que la pregunta YA ESTABA RESPONDIDA Y ACEPTADA con una buena respuesta. Poner despues cosas que son peores solo puede complicar a la gente y es una pesima respuesta.

Comment: Si he contestado es por que no he visto que estaba respondida.

Comment: Entiendo que eres Juez o Administrador o algo similar para decir que es una respuesta 'PESIMA'

Comment: No soy ni juez ni administrador ni nada, solo tengo sentido comun.

Comment: Pues entonces, querido compañero, no puedes constatar que una respuesta es pésima, simplemente por tu lo creas así.

Comment: Ademas, de todo esto eso del código de conducta por se nuevo y tal... no existe?

Comment: Hay cosas que son obvias, no hace falta mas que eso.

Comment: No quiero extender mas esto, hay miles de formas de hacer la cosas, mas simples o mas complicadas. Vale muchacho tu ganas.